# Ask IntelliJ to follow a Maven POM to build the project internally (Build Project, for testing, debugging) and not its own procedure, when it fails?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, build

At work, at home, on open source projects, I often face the same trouble:

1. I download a project. I compile it from a command line with *Maven* and succeed.
2. I open *IntelliJ*: it detects a *Maven* project, solve it, and show me its sources without errors.
3. Then I ask it to *Build Project*. And it fails with a message depicting a trouble that doesn't exist.

Then, I can't :

- Start a debug session
- Run a single test or test class from the IDE

Because *IntelliJ* wants to build the project its own way first, but is failing to do so.

How to set *IntelliJ* to use only *Maven* and a specified pom to build/refresh the project, when it needs so? And not to attempt another way, that doesn't succeed?

---

(*) The project I'm attempting to build with the *Build Project* of *IntelliJ* is https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/branch-3.5 that compiles with *Maven* in a command line, is shown without errors when opened with *IntelliJ*, and fail to build with *Build Project*:

[image]

Because it attempts to do anything that isn't asked in any pom.
The mentioned `import` does exist, of course.

---

To reproduce:

1. Download https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/branch-3.5
2. Compile it with *Maven*: it compiles (skip tests, if you wish to go faster)
3. Then, with *IntelliJ*, attempt a *Build Project* or to run a test, or to start a debug. It will fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options that you have listed are processed by IDEA's native Build System.
The native Build System is intended to be as close as possible to Maven, but there might be discrepancies for the Projects with more advanced build logic and/or structure.

For Maven-based Projects it is best to use options available from the [Maven Tool Window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-projects-tool-window.html) and Maven's [Run/Debug Configurations](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-maven.html).

If you are still experiencing issues, enable "[Delegate IDE build/run actions to Maven](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-runner.html)" option from `Settings / Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven -> Runner`.

Comment: Thanks! It's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Idea just resolves maven dependencies and compile in its [own way](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/compiling-applications.html). So if some executions of maven goal is a must for compiling the project, it may cause idea build fail. Maybe you can [run a package jar directly](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/compiling-applications.html#run_packaged_jar) for debug as a workaround. Or figure out what maven goal should be executed.

Comment: Does it mean that the `jar` to debug must have a main class? Not sure that any of this project carries one. Will I need to find the `jars` that must be in the classpath of the `jar` I'm willing to run? For example: `spark-sql.jar` could need `spark-core.jar`, etc.? And how to run a test?